# Mac Localhost I cannot access from my phone

Tags: macos, xampp, localhost

Hi everyone I try to access my localhost on my iphone or android phone I have the 2 I followed several tutorials, without success I thought I really did everything before asking for help here. here are some details: My config: Mac os big on Ethernet connection not wifi (maybe that's the problem) is that I already did, I type my ip in the browser of my phone (Setting -> shared). ifconfig sa did not work. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and I had to change my host from `localhost` to `0.0.0.0`. For example, I was trying to run my Gatsby site and I had to do `gatsby develop --host 0.0.0.0`

After that, when I opened `http://<MY MAC'S IP ADDRESS>:<MY WEBSITE PORT>` it worked